# How do I get a list of Amazon regions via the command line?

Tags: cloud, aws

I'd like to see how I can get a list of regions from AWS on the command line so I can quickly look things up, how can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by running the command *ec2-describe-regions* from the command line (if you have ec2-api-tools installed available in multiverse).

```
$ ec2-describe-regions
REGION  eu-west-1   ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  sa-east-1   ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  us-east-1   ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  ap-northeast-1  ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  us-west-2   ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
REGION  us-west-1   ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  ap-southeast-1  ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Yeah, about that.  You need a default region configured before this will work (3 years later, still ?). So google is your friend. Regions and endpoints (rande - nmemonically randy)  here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html.   Why they could not just default to us-east-1 when this is attempted before configuration is beyond me ?

Comment: @mckenzm lol "rande - mnemonically randy" I thought that was just something happening inside *my* head.  Google probably has a laugh at the number of times I've googled "amazon rande".  I assume the reason for not using a default endpoint is that it would put much the burden on that one single region's endpoints, and would be unnecessarily slow for a large percentage of users who are closer to another region.  It also might be related to the flow of logic inside aws-cli -- perhaps the "ec2" part requires endpoint selection before "describe-regions" is actually understood.  Wild guesses.

Comment: `You need a default region configured before this will work` any way to get the region without specifying any region?

Answer (score 16):

This is now how you'd do it using the aws cli:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-regions --output table
----------------------------------------------------------
|                     DescribeRegions                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
||                        Regions                       ||
|+-----------------------------------+------------------+|
||             Endpoint              |   RegionName     ||
|+-----------------------------------+------------------+|
||  ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com      |  eu-west-1       ||
||  ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com |  ap-southeast-1  ||
||  ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com |  ap-southeast-2  ||
||  ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com   |  eu-central-1    ||
||  ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com |  ap-northeast-2  ||
||  ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com |  ap-northeast-1  ||
||  ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com      |  us-east-1       ||
||  ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com      |  sa-east-1       ||
||  ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com      |  us-west-1       ||
||  ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com      |  us-west-2       ||
|+-----------------------------------+------------------+|
```

Answer (score 0):

[Botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore) would have all of them in configured endpoints:

```
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boto/botocore/develop/botocore/data/endpoints.json | grep -B1 desc|grep {|cut -d \" -f2
```

Your AWS CLI installation may have it locally;  In this example, [I get at it with python](https://gist.github.com/axelabs/f5e72a8c6a033fbfa88b13ea1d3be299#file-regions-py):

```
$ python3 << :]
> #!/usr/bin/env python3.7
> 
> import botocore, json
> from pathlib import Path
>  
> with open("{}/{}".format(Path(botocore.__file__).resolve().parent, "data/endpoints.json"), 'r') as e:
>     for p in json.load(e)['partitions']:
>         print("{}:\t\t{}".format(p['partitionName']," ".join(p['regions'].keys())))
> :]
AWS Standard:           af-south-1 ap-east-1 ap-northeast-1 ap-northeast-2 ap-northeast-3 ap-south-1 ap-southeast-1 ap-southeast-2 ap-southeast-3 ca-central-1 eu-central-1 eu-north-1 eu-south-1 eu-west-1 eu-west-2 eu-west-3 me-south-1 sa-east-1 us-east-1 us-east-2 us-west-1 us-west-2
AWS China:              cn-north-1 cn-northwest-1
AWS GovCloud (US):              us-gov-east-1 us-gov-west-1
AWS ISO (US):           us-iso-east-1 us-iso-west-1
AWS ISOB (US):          us-isob-east-1
```